# How to overlay controls over a camera view in Phonegap 3.2.0?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, overlay

I would like to reproduce the following screen in Phonegap, overlaying thumbnails and a button over the camera view

How can this be achieved to work on both Android and iOS, I am open to ideas

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can only do this by writing native code in each language. It could be possible to do so by creating a phonegap plugin.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Would you suggest creatinga custom plugin that will be maintained by me adjacent to the phonegap code, can we have a whole screen implemented as a plugin, so we can switch to it from inside the app, will this be performent?

Comment: Yes, I would start by searching for native solutions related to camera overlays (there are many for both languages as this is a common request of mobile developers) and then research creating a phonegap plugin. One existing plugin that may be helpful is the barcode scanner. This makes use of camera overlays in both iOS and Android. https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner

Comment: @DawsonLoudon - Did you manage to achieve this? i am currently trying to do the same and would be grateful to hear if and how you did this.

Comment: @DavidMZ - Did you manage to achieve this as a cordova plugin? Have the same requirement. Thanks.