# Overlaying an image on camera on Android using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to place a simple png image over the camera view using PhoneGap on Android.

I've been search for days, but all the topics for phonegap overlays on Android come up with no real answer. Some point to a native objective-C iPhone version and suggest "just do the same for Android".

How would I do this? Is there an example for Android?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20910916/276648